# Firestore Search for Values in Multiple Arrays

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have two arrays in each of my Firestore documents. In my app you can search based on values in those arrays. I am able to get my search working if I look for exact matches between my arrays that get created based on what options are selected and look for exact matches in my documents like this.

```
let _ = circleQuery.observe(.documentEntered, with: { (key, location) in
            if let key = key {
                Constants.firestore.collection("facilities").whereField("facility_type", isEqualTo: self.type!)
                    .whereField("insurance_accepted", isEqualTo: self.insurance!).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                        if let err = error {
                            print(err.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            for document in (querySnapshot?.documents)! {
                                if document.documentID == key {
                                    self.facilities?.append(document.data())
                                    self.addFaciltiesToMap()
                                }
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
        })
```

The problem with this is that that this isn't looking at individual values. I want to display results based on whether to not a value from my local array is contained in the two document arrays. The user has options that can be selected from each of those arrays and they don't have to select from both so they can select options that are only contained in one or the other. For example, they can select between 0 and 4 options from the "facility_type" array and between 0 and 2 options from the "insurance_accepted" array. So, if they only select options from "facility_type", I only want to look for the selected values in that document array and the same goes for the "insurance_accepted" document array. If they select options from both, I need to look for options in both. If they are only selecting from one or the other, I need to return results based on whether their selected values exists in that one array in the document. If they select both I need to return results based on whether to not at least one match is made in each document array.

This is basically what I'm trying to achieve.

```
for value in self.type! {
                    Constants.firestore.collection("facilities").whereField("facility_type", arrayContains: value).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                        if let err = error {
                            print(err.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            for document in (querySnapshot?.documents)! {
                                if document.documentID == key {
                                    self.facilities?.append(document.data())
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                for value in self.insurance! {
                    Constants.firestore.collection("facilities").whereField("insurance_accepted", arrayContains: value).getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
                        if let err = error {
                            print(err.localizedDescription)
                        } else {
                            for document in (querySnapshot?.documents)! {
                                if document.documentID == key {
                                    self.facilities?.append(document.data())
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: It sounds like you need to read about arrayContains filters.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership

Comment: My issue is that only one arrayContains filter can be used per query so I'm not entirely sure how to go about this when I need to look in two arrays.

Comment: You can search two arrays by having multiple where clauses.  The documentation for that is on the same page I linked.  Are you saying that's not working?

Comment: This is what I was referring to. "you can include at most one array_contains clause in a compound query"

Comment: Ah, I see.  Sounds like you need a different database structure to support your query.  How about a new array that contains only the common elements of the other two?

Comment: @DougStevenson There are no common elements between the two arrays. One contains ["Detox", "Outpatient", "MAT", "IOP"] and the other is ["HMO", "PPO"]

Comment: Instead of lists, you will need to use an object where the values of the lists are instead fields of the objects, and they all just map to 'true'.

Comment: @DougStevenson That seems to have worked. Thanks!